# AndroidStudio Gitログの日本語が文字化けする

Tags: git, android-studio

AndroidStudio 2.1.2 の versionControl で Gitログが文字化けしています
OS は Ubuntu 14.04 LTS です
コンソールからは git log で日本語表示されるのですが・・・

よろしくお願いいたします

Answer (score 0, accepted):

全部試してみてください。

## 設定を変更

`File>Settings>`をクリックしそこから`Editor＞File Encodings`を選択してください。
そして、`Project Encoding:`を`UTF-8`に変更して下さい。

## ファイルの文字コードを変更

ファイルを編集をする画面で、右下にある文字コードが表示されているところをクリックし、`UTF-8`に変更してください。

## build.gradleを編集

`build.gradle`に次のコードを追加してください。

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }
```

全体のコードはこんな感じ？

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
 
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
 
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }
 
}
 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

ただ、Ubuntuの標準文字コードは、UTF-8だったと思うので、改善になるかわかりませんが。

### 追記

調べてみるとフォントの問題らしいです。
設定画面から、Appearanceを選択し、Override default fonts byにチェックを入れます。そしたら日本語が扱えるフォントになると思います。
[参考ページ](http://xshima2.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-87.html)も載せておきます。

Comment: sunsolar-arrowさん、こんにちは

上記の設定をすべて試してみましたが、改善されませんでした

AndroidStudio のエディタ画面のコメントなどは問題なく日本語で表示されるのですが
VersionControl の Log だけが文字化けしている状態です
ネットで検索しても同じような問題を抱えている書き込みが見つからないので質問いたしました

AndroidStudio の VersionControl 用のエンコーディングの設定方法とかあるのでしょうか？

Comment: @user12477 やっぱり改善されませんでしたか。VersionControl用の設定については調べておきます。

Comment: @user12477  フォントの問題らしいですよ。回答を編集します。

Comment: 無事に日本語で表示されるようになりました

私の環境はこちらの設定 Override default fonts by に チェック Name:ubuntu になってました
これがデフォルトの設定なのか忘れましたが、AndroidStudio をインストール直後に設定をいじったのかもしれません
ちなみに、Override default fonts by のチェックを外しても日本語表示されました